# Do I need server side rendering if I have 10% static page and 90% SPA?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, server-side-rendering

I have to build an app in Angular that is supposed to act as Single-page app, but within it I need to have say 2 pages that are plain old simple HTML without any dynamic data - a simple landing page with some info about what the app is about, what it does, who should use it... just basic stuff. Of course, this part should be SEO optimized and loaded as fast as possible.

My question is do I need Server-side rendering for this part? If the answer is yes, could this be done with an existing server since I will have one for API? I've noticed in Angular SSR is done with Angular Universal and they mention server module in every guide/tutorial but as far as I understand this would be redundant if you already have a server for API.

The other way to do this would be serving static HTML pages, would this be enough? I would guess having 2 static HTMLs for landing pages and another one that wraps SPA would suffice?

Comment: Nö you don’t need server side rendering, at least not while serving the static resources. If the file content is quite complicated or you want easy editing you might want to run it through some generation steps at build time. (However if you have a common navigation frame or need JavaScript navigation actions your pages might not be as static as you need them to be)

Comment: Why would you server side-render a static HTML page? Isn't the RESULT of server side render a static HTML page?

Comment: Thanks. I guess not utilizing Angular components for building blocks of these static pages would be a trade off.

Comment: But let's say I opt in for SSR because I need to use certain templating engine for whatever reason - would it be possible to use the same server I use for API? What are the next steps? I'm having difficulties researching this because I didn't see any tutorial or guide mentioning using existing server for SSR, they only mention creating new .js file within the Angular project and importing node/express server there.

Comment: Would this be the part I'm looking for? 
https://angular.io/guide/universal#using-absolute-urls-for-server-requests

Comment: Yeah in that guide they use `server.ts` file which creates another server for this but I want to use existing server that I already use for API.

Comment: Unless those two pages aren't part of your Angular app, then yes, you're going to need Angular Universal to get any SEO on those URLs, otherwise there's not going to be anything to spider. If these pages are navigated to as components within your Angular app, and you don't use Universal, a spider won't see any HTML to index.

Comment: Not sure which server you use but if it can serve the static index.html and packaged JavaScript resources it certainly can serve two more files (if route is configured correctly)